# is there a function version of >, <, == comparators in R?

Tags: r, function, comparator

Is there a built-in function for comparators in R? For example `gt(3, 2)` being equivalent to `3 > 2`?

Comment: yes `\`<\`(3, 2)`

Comment: Not exactly, but there is something like that in `magic` package.

Comment: rawr - if you make that an answer I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting Rawr's answer in the comments here as the official answer. Use:

```
`<`(3, 2)
```